# Javadoc not found - jakarta.servlet (Tomcat 10.0.23, Apache Netbeans 13, JDK 1.8.0_321)

Tags: netbeans, javadoc, jakarta-migration

By default, Netbeans 13 template using javax, which is not included in Jarkata EE platform equipped by Tomcat 10. So I replace all javax by Jakarta package.
But I can't see or perform show javadoc.

[image: javadoc not found image]

[image: version web.xml]

What can I do to fix it?

[Jakarta Servlet API v6.0.0](https://javadoc.io/doc/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/latest/jakarta.servlet/module-summary.html)

I tried adding the above .jar file to the project in Netbeans but it didn't work

Comment: You have a far bigger problem than being unable to locate a javadoc; [your use of Java 8 with NetBeans 13 is unsupported](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb13/nb13.html): _"The Apache NetBeans 13 binary releases require JDK 11+, and officially support running on JDK 11 and JDK 17."_. So update NetBeans 13 to use a valid JDK release (i.e. >= 11), then update your question as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

After you have changed your JDK to newer version, as the previous answer suggested, and if you are using maven you can right click on your project, then go *Run Maven*->*Goals*, and in *Goals* field, type **dependency:sources**, and then click ok. Provided you previously specified jakarta dependencies you want in your pom.xml file, this should solve your problem.